# UITabBarController unable to set view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller

I'm trying to set the view for my UITabBarController to always be the middle item with the following code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UITabBarController *tabBarController = (UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController;
    tabBarController.selectedIndex = 2;
}
```

But it still points towards the first item. Shouldn't this work?

Comment: have you checked ?, your window rootViewController is tabbarcontroller.  why you need this even "tabBarController.selectedIndex = 2;" should work for you.

Comment: If you are inside your UITabBarController, just call self.selectedIndex = 2;

Comment: thanks: self.selectedIndex = 2; worked

Comment: I will add it as answer and accept it as the correct answer

Answer (score 0):

inside your UITabBarController call:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   [super viewDidLoad];

   self.selectedIndex = 2;
}
```